# Dirac notation in quantum mechanics

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, notation

I've just started studying quantum mechanics and couldn't understand why is operator applied at right side of bra vector? I really can't get any idea of this.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easiest to understand Dirac notation by considering a special case, in which the Hilbert space has finitely many (say, three) dimensions. Then you can represent the elements of the theory using the normal tools of linear algebra. Specifically, kets are column vectors (which are $3\times 1$ matrices in our example), bras are row vectors (which are $1\times3$), and operators are square matrices ($3\times3$).

Matrix multiplication only makes sense when you multiply an $m\times n$ matrix with an $n \times p$ matrix (which gives you an $m\times p$ matrix). Multiplying a bra with an operator on the right means you multiply a $1\times3$ and a $3\times3$ matrix, giving you a $1\times 3$ matrix (another bra) as a result. However, if you were to try to act with the operator on the *left* of the bra, then you would be multiplying a $3\times 3$ matrix with a $1\times 3$ matrix, which doesn't make sense due to the way matrix multiplication is defined.